# Maxima simplify expression with diff

Tags: diff, constants, maxima

Let's assume a is a constant and x is my variable with respect to time, so basically x(t).

Then in Maxima , what is the best way to replace `'diff(a*x,t)` with `a*'diff(x,t)` automatically without use subst command.

The reason I don't to use subst is that I have many variables and higher order derivatives. It is not efficient to use subst to replace all the occurrences.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I have tried with `depends(x,t)` command, but it only works with the simple case. Here is an minimal example of my situation.

```
depends([x,y],t);
eq1:diff(x,t)-b=c;
eq2:subst([x=a*y],eq1);
sol_dy=solve(eq2,diff(y,t))
```

Of course here a,b,c are constants and x, y are variables on t.
Maxima can not solve diff(y,t) directly. How do deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that `'diff(...)` (i.e. derivative noun expression) isn't linear (doesn't distribute over `+` and doesn't factor out constants) but `diff(...)` (verb expression) is linear. That's a misfeature, at least.

I was going to suggest `declare(nounify(diff), linear)` but that makes derivatives come out as 0 in your example ... this is probably a bug, I'll have to think more about it.

Try `ev(eq2, nouns);` to re-evaluate the derivatives as verbs -- I think that should cause the constant to factor out.